# Winnovative pdf converter throws messege - This operation requires IIS version 7.5 or higher running in integrated pipeline mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, winnovative

I'm using winnovative PDF converter and its working properly on my test project. but when i add same code to my original project,

shows that it throws following exceptions.
[image: exception]![enter image description here]

i checked value of

```
 HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;
```

and it shows values as above content.

how can I solve this. I tried this even after hosting in IIS server as well.

**Edit:**

```
byte[] pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(htmlWithSvgUrl);

HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;

// add the Content-Type and Content-Disposition HTTP headers
httpResponse.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
httpResponse.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=SvgToPdf.pdf; size={0}", pdfBytes.Length.ToString()));

// write the PDF document bytes as attachment to HTTP response 
httpResponse.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);

// Note: it is important to end the response, otherwise the ASP.NET
// web page will render its content to PDF document stream
//httpResponse.End();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: Are you using IIS 7.5 or higher and is your application pool set to *Integrated pipeline mode*?

Comment: @Stijn even i run this in iis 7.5 its not working. in this case it's not throw any exception. only PDF is not generated. so because of that i look into `Response` and it shows above exceptions

Comment: Can you check what the output of `System.Web.HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline` and `System.Web.HttpRuntime.IISVersion` is?

Answer (score 0):

If your IIS version is 7.5 or higher, then the exception message which we should focus may be "this operation requires iis integrated pipeline mode"

I found this answer from this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1253457.aspx

> As the error message indicated, it requires IIS integrated pipeline
>   mode. Please select the application pool in IIS Manager, Click "Basic
>   Settings..." and make sure "Integrated" mode is selected for "Managed
>   pipeline mode" in the dialog.

Could you please check that?

Comment: even i run this in iis 7.5 its not working. in this case it's not throw any exception. only PDF is not generated. so because of that i look into `Response` and it shows above exceptions

Comment: Could you please try this code instead?

**Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=SvgToPdf.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);**

Comment: even nothing change.. still pdf is not generated.

Comment: Have you had put breakpoint and debug your code? I would know which line was thrown the exception.

Comment: its not thrown any exception. but when i put break point in `HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;` line it shows above pic info

Comment: Have you used **UpdatePanel** Control with the button (any control for user to click and then do the exporting PDF)? If so you have to add a post back trigger for that UpdatePanel